# Ruby class initialize override module initialize

Tags: ruby

I am using `super` to pass arguments to the parent `initialize` method, which is not called by default. This is what it looks like. (Notice the use of `super` on the last two arguments)

```
module Pet
  def initialize name, is_pet
    @is_pet = is_pet
    if is_pet
      @name = name
    else
      @name = "Unnamed"
    end
  end
  def pet?
    return @is_pet
  end
  def get_name
    return @name
  end
end

class Dog
  include Pet
  def initialize tricks, name, is_pet
    @tricks = tricks
    super name, is_pet
  end
  def get_tricks
    return @tricks
  end
end
```

Here's what I can do with it:

```
d = Dog.new ["roll", "speak", "play dead"], "Spots", true

d.pet?       #=> true
d.get_tricks #=> ["roll", "speak", "play dead"]
d.get_name   #=> "Spots"
```

It works fine, but I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: you don't need `return` as the last value is automatically the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is not a good programming practice to hard code a fixed string like `"Unnamed"` as the value for `@name`. In such case, you should assign `nil`, and do whatever modification to it when you print it. Suppose you do this.
- Then `is_pet` can be deduced from whether `name` is `nil` or not, so it is redundant to have that as an instance variable. You can simply apply `!!` to `name` in order to get `is_pet`. Therefore, you should get rid of such instance variable.
- You have `get_` prefixes as getter methods, but in Ruby, it is a better practice to have the same name as the instance variables (without the atmark) as the getter name.

This will give you:

```
module Pet
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize name; @name = name end
end

class Dog
  include Pet
  attr_reader :tricks
  def initialize tricks, name
    @tricks = tricks
    super(name)
  end
end

d = Dog.new ["roll", "speak", "play dead"], "Spots"
d.tricks #=> ["roll", "speak", "play dead"]
d.name   #=> "Spots"
!!d.name #=> true (= `is_pet`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not write code that calls `super` to get into an included module. Don't write modules that will expect children to call super. That's not the point of modules.

It's good object oriented style to not ask about what things are. Look up "tell, don't ask" and duck typing in general.

If you want to provide a default `initialize` method, you *probably* want inheritance. But there are occasionally valid use cases for overriding initialize in a module. The idiomatic thing to do here is a hook method:

```
module Pet
  def initialize(options = {})
    @name = options[:name]
    post_initialize(options)
  end

  def post_initialize(options = {})
    # can be overridden in including modules
  end
end

class Dog
  include Pet

  def post_initialize(options = {})
    @tricks = options[:tricks]
  end
end

dog = Dog.new(name: "Fido", tricks: ["play dead", "roll over"])
```

A module is for including some shared behavior among many different things. It's good to consider it like an adjective describing what you might do with a class that includes it. Words that end in "-able" (like `Enumerable` or `Comparable`), describing a receiving class, or "-or" (`Iterator`, `Interactor`), describing a doing class, are good candidates for being modules.

Comment: The reason I'm using a module to do this is because I have multiple classes inheriting from the "Mammal" class. The Dog is inheriting from "Mammal" so I can't also inherit from Pet. Also pet is more of a blanket and less an object, and I thought that's what modules did.